# Имитировать стандартную иконку загрузки браузера на JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть ajax навигация по страницам:

```
var nav = {
 go: function(a) {
  // лоадер
  $.get('...', function(data) {
   // прячем лоадер
   ...
  });
 }
}
```

Возможно ли как-то имитировать стандартную иконку загрузки favicon браузера, т.е чтобы пока не пришел ответ от $.get, крутилась браузерная иконка загрузки в favicon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, но это не будет кроссбраузерно.

Comment: Можно определять браузер и подставлять его иконку

Comment: @knes, можно и через iframe. Но что грузить в нем?